# want to show master & detail object s records on vfp

Tags: visualforce, master-detail

i m trying to show trainer deals  object data & trainer master object data on sameVFP. , it is showing only training deals(details obj) data  but not trainer master data.(master objt)

controller:

```
public class trainingDealclass {
  public list<Trainer_master__c> traininglist{get;set;}

     public trainingdealclass(){
        traininglist= [SELECT First_name__c, Last_name__c, Education__c,SELECT Course_c  FROM CRN_Training_deals__r)
                      FROM Trainer_master__c LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

---

VFP

```
<apex:page controller="TrainingDealClass">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:Pageblock title="training details">
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!traininglist}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.First_name__c}"></apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Last_name__c}"></apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!a.Education__c}"></apex:column>
           
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.CRN_Training_deals__r}" var="b">  
            <apex:column value="{!b.Course__c}"></apex:column>
             </apex:pageBlockTable>
            
        </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:Pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! (1) please use the tools in the editor to format your code, or use triple backticks (```) around each code block. (2) the Apex code in your post is not compilable (the SOQL is incorrect). Please include valid code to reproduce your issue. Check out [ask] to learn more, and [help/on-topic]. Thanks!

Comment: Do you field level permission on profile for the fields queried on Trainer_master__c? also your pageblock should be nested in <apex:column></apex:column>

Comment: yes, it has field level permission. but still error